# Convert string to int in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, router

I'm trying to make an aggregate through a collection, and take the movies from 1930 to 1949, but in the schema I made the movies string, is there a way to make the condition work?

```
router.post("/golden", async (req, res) => {
  let carouselTemp = [];
  carouselTemp = await Movie.aggregate([
    { $sample: { size: 10 } },
    { $match: { $and: [{ year: { $gte: "1939" } }, { year: { $lte: "1949" } }] } }])
  try {
    ids = []
    carouselTemp.forEach(elem => {
      ids.push(elem._id);
    })
    const newCarousel = new Carousel({
      title: "Golden Age Movies",
      genre: "Golden",
      content: ids,
    });
    newCarousel.save();
    res.status(200).json(newCarousel);
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked out [$toInt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)?

Comment: I found something about it, but I didn't know how to implement it in my match

Comment: [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rh6hYXggYI3) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: You can use the string values of the `year` field for matching - your query works okay. In general, storing numbers as string types is not a good practice.

Comment: Actually, what is not working for you?